# flutter how to make card in leading of listview

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to make UI like my upper image but I cant make like that But it is not being made as you are seeing in the image below.

I want to make leading of ListTile part like this .

[image]

But I can't make it please help me.
this is my code and UI

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, left: 10, right: 10),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                Text(
                  'Your rooms',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                Spacer(),
                Card(
                  elevation: 1,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                  ),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Text('add',
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.grey)),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.add,
                          size: 20,
                          color: Colors.grey,
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            Container(
              height: 110,
              width: 380,
              // color: Colors.red,
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                color: Color(0xffbbf0e3),
              ),
              child: Center(
                child: ListTile(
                  leading: Container(
                    // height: 10,
                    width: 100,
                    child: Card(
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                      elevation: 1,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          // borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          // color: Colors.red,
                        ),
                        child: CircleAvatar(
                          radius: 25,
                          backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                              'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTkNWsvdJGKCRYW_Wb-K40Po2JQ8LpooWoilw&usqp=CAU'),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  // leading: Card(
                  //     shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  //         borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                  //     elevation: 1,
                  //     color: Colors.white,
                  //     child: Container(
                  //       height: 80,
                  //       width: 75,
                  //       decoration:  BoxDecoration(
                  //         // borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                  //         shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  //         // color: Colors.red,
                  //       ),
                  //       child: CircleAvatar(
                  //         radius: 25,
                  //         backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                  //             'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTkNWsvdJGKCRYW_Wb-K40Po2JQ8LpooWoilw&usqp=CAU'),
                  //       ),
                  //     )),
                  title: Text(
                    "Living room",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                  ),
                  subtitle: Text(
                    '3 turned on',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                        fontSize: 20,
                        color: Colors.green),
                  ),
                  trailing: Card(
                    elevation: 1,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                    ),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                      child: Container(
                        width: 50,
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Text('5',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 20, color: Colors.grey)),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 1,
                            ),
                            Icon(
                              Icons.electrical_services,
                              textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                              size: 20,
                              color: Colors.grey,
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

I am making like this .

Comment: what exactly is the problem with the Leading? is it that it isn't a circle?

Comment: use margin property of Container widget.

Answer (score 3):

I removed some unnecessary Lines of Code and voilà there you go:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, left: 10, right: 10),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                Text(
                  'Your rooms',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                Spacer(),
                Card(
                  elevation: 1,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                  ),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Text('add',
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.grey)),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.add,
                          size: 20,
                          color: Colors.grey,
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            Container(
              height: 110,
              width: 380,
              // color: Colors.red,
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                color: Color(0xffbbf0e3),
              ),
              child: Center(
                child: ListTile(
                  leading: CircleAvatar( // I ONLY CHANGED THIS PART
                          radius: 25,
                          backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                              'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTkNWsvdJGKCRYW_Wb-K40Po2JQ8LpooWoilw&usqp=CAU'),
                  ),
                  // leading: Card(
                  //     shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  //         borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                  //     elevation: 1,
                  //     color: Colors.white,
                  //     child: Container(
                  //       height: 80,
                  //       width: 75,
                  //       decoration:  BoxDecoration(
                  //         // borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                  //         shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  //         // color: Colors.red,
                  //       ),
                  //       child: CircleAvatar(
                  //         radius: 25,
                  //         backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                  //             'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTkNWsvdJGKCRYW_Wb-K40Po2JQ8LpooWoilw&usqp=CAU'),
                  //       ),
                  //     )),
                  title: Text(
                    "Living room",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                  ),
                  subtitle: Text(
                    '3 turned on',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                        fontSize: 20,
                        color: Colors.green),
                  ),
                  trailing: Card(
                    elevation: 1,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                    ),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                      child: Container(
                        width: 50,
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Text('5',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 20, color: Colors.grey)),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 1,
                            ),
                            Icon(
                              Icons.electrical_services,
                              textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                              size: 20,
                              color: Colors.grey,
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: but I want some white background behind image

Comment: but I want some white background behind image like top image.

Comment: @Deepak you cant get a white background on the image if it is not transparent. Your image isn't so it is not possible, the best thing you could do is to have a white background on the image itself, if you have a transparent Image you could use a Container, give that a white Background and put the image as a child, no need for a Card there.